# How can I calculate the equivalent resistance of this circuit with resistors in parallel with wires?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

**Problem:**

> Calculate the equivalent resistance, $R_\text{eq} ,$ of this circuit:
>
> $\hspace{50px}$[image].

---

#### My solution attempt

1. Тhe $12 \, \Omega$ resistor and the $6\, \Omega$ resistor are in parallel, so$$
   R
   = {\left(\frac{1}{12\,\Omega} + \frac{1}{6\,\Omega} \right)}^{-1}
   = 4\,\Omega
   \,,
   \tag{1}
   $$

   reducing the circuit diagram to:
   $\hspace{50px}$[image].
2. The $4 \,\Omega$ resistor and the $12 \,\Omega$ resistor are in series, so$$
   R
   = 12\,\Omega + 4\,\Omega
   = 16\,\Omega
   \,,
   \tag{2}
   $$

   reducing the circuit diagram to:
   $\hspace{50px}$[image].

I am not sure of the answer, and I am so confused right now.

I am totally new to circuits and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the top circuit diagram exactly as it appears in the book?

Comment: @BobD Yep , it's exactly the same

Comment: The reason I ask is the 12 ohm resistor on the left is short-circuited by the wire and can be replaced by a wire. Then you have a parallel combination of 6 ohm and 12 ohms and that would give you an answer different than the book.

Comment: I see 4 Ohms also

Comment: how do you tell if a resistor is  short-circuited or not ?

Comment: If you put 1 V on the + side and 0 V on the - side then you get 1/12 A through the top and 1/6 A through the bottom side. That is 1/4 A total for an equivalent resistance of 4 ohm

Comment: The 12 ohm resistor on the left is in parallel to a 0 ohm link, so it's short-circuited, and that part of the circuit has a resistance of 0 ohms. Using + for series and | for parallel, the circuit is `((0 | 12) + 12) | 6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not supposed to provide solutions to homework and exercise questions, only guidance.

So here is some guidance;

The top circuit diagram below is your top diagram. The bottom diagram is equivalent to the top diagram, as long as all the "wires" shown are considered ideal (that is, zero resistance).

So given the bottom diagram, what should the answer be, regardless of what the "book" says.

Hope this  helps

[image]